# Best way of removing duplicates from a list by object attribute

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a list of objects, and I want to filter the list in a way that as a result there is only one occurence of each attribute value.

For instance, let's say I have three objects

```
obj1.my_attr = 'a'
obj2.my_attr = 'b'
obj3.my_attr = 'b'

obj_list = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

And and the end, I want to get `[obj1, obj2]`. Actually order does not matter, so `[obj1, obj3]` is exactly as good.

First I thought of the typical imperative clunky ways like following:

```
record = set()
result = []

for obj in obj_list:
    if obj.my_attr not in record:
        record.add(obj.my_attr)
        result.append(obj)
```

Then I though of maping it to a dictionary, use the key to override any previous entry and finally extract the values:

```
result = {obj.my_attr: obj for obj in obj_list}.values()
```

This one looks good, but I would like to know if there any more elegant, efficient or functional way of achieving this. Maybe some sweet thing hidden in the standard library... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use a functional programming style in Python, you may want to check out the [toolz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toolz/) package.  With `toolz`, you could simply do:

```
toolz.unique(obj_list, key=lambda x: x.my_attr)
```

For better performance, you could use `operator.attrgetter('my_attr')` instead of the lambda function for the key.  You could also use [cytoolz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cytoolz/), which is a fast implementation of `toolz` written in Cython.

Comment: This exactly fills the FP gap I was missing in python. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object that would define a custom `__hash__` function:

```
class HashMyAttr:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.obj.my_attr.__hash__()
    def __eq__(self, other):
         return self.obj.my_attr == other.obj.my_attr
```

And use it like:

```
obj_list = [x.obj for x in set(HashMyAttr(obj) for obj in obj_list)]
```

Comment: Not quite. Doesn't work if the attribute is an `int`: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__eq__'`

Comment: in this case  the attribute appears to be a string, but I guess `==` would work, then.

Comment: This definitely works and is an interesting approach, but I find it a little bit of overkill and quite verbose. I would prefer to use the dictionary comprehension instead (most probably more efficient, since it does not need to construct wrappers).

Comment: If you can override the `__eq__` and the `__hash__` functions directly in the original class of your objects, then you don't need most of the overhead here.

Comment: @njzk2 and what if I need to filter later by another attribute? or I have already a `__hash__` implementation?

Comment: that's why I offered this alternative using a wrapping class. You could add the name of the attribute in the constructor and use getattr, or pass a lambda or use a function, to have something more flexible.